# How to set FindGraphCommunities Modularity's method option

Tags: graphs-and-networks

It is possible to set 2 options for one of FindGraphCommunities's methods "Modularity". They are "Weighted" and "StopTest".

The question is how can one use the second option "StopTest"? What values/pure functions does it take?

Comment: Where do you find this second option? When I look at `FindGraphCommunities` I only see the `Method` option.

Comment: @bill s, there's a special syntax to set options: Method->{MethodName, OptionName->Option}. So the user can provide some random string for OptionName to produce an error message. This error message says "OptionName is not in {"Weighted", "StopTest"}". So that is the way to find out what are the options available for that method.

Comment: I see. Oddly, I get the same error message even if I have `OptionName->"Weighted"` or `OptionName->"StopTest"`. So it's not clear these options are really implemented. Have you been able to do anything with them?

Comment: sorry, I may have not put it as clear as I should. OptionName is a placeholder for "Weighted". Try for ex. Method->{"Modularity","Weighted"->True} or {"Modularity","Weighted"->False}. This should produce different results in general for weighted graphs (and no errors).

Comment: So you could guess that `Weighted->False` analyzes a weighted graph as if it were unweighted. Not sure about `StopTest`. If you find any documentation about these, please post so we can all see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method "Modularity" starts with each vertex in its own community and then iteratively merges them to maximize the proportion of edges contained within communities minus the expected proportion that would be in the communities if the edges were randomly placed.

Details here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_(networks)

The "StopTest" option expects a boolean-valued function that takes the graph as the first parameter and the list of vertex communities for the current iteration as the second parameter. You can, for example, use the stop test to halt the merging of communities early if there is a specific number of communities that you want to be returned. Using an example from the documentation that contains three communities with default options, we can stop it early to find five communities.

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
   8 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
   7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8}]

FindGraphCommunities[g, 
 Method -> {"Modularity", "StopTest" -> (Length@#2 == 5 &)}]
```