# FindGraphCommunities method options?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

`FindGraphCommunitites` has a couple of method options: `"Modularity"`, `"Hierarchical"`, `"Spectral"`, `"Centrality"`, and `"CliquePercolation"`.

I know that some of these methods admit further options. For example, `"Modularity"` admits `"StopTest"` and `"Weighted"`, which can be specified as:

```
FindGraphCommunitites[graph, Method->{"Modularity", "Weighted"->False,
   "StopTest"->"StopTest" -> (Length@#2 == 7 &)}
```

(`"StopTest"` example from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28449/534).

Where can I find documentation or references as to what options each method admits, and what do they mean?

See also: [Citation of the algorithms used in FindGraphCommunities](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58136/534), [How to set FindGraphCommunities Modularity's method option](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27969/534).

Comment: You might want to contact Wolfram support directly with this.  When you receive a response, please share the information in an answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs I sent them an email. If I receive a reply I'll post it here. In the meantime, and in case I don't receive any reply from Wolfram, maybe people in this forum with experience using `FindGraphCommunitites` may want to share what they have learned.

Comment: Did you receive a response from support?

Comment: @Szabolcs Nope :(

Comment: [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has a set of community detection functions. The documentation has links to the corresponding publication for each one.