# how to successively plot Community Graphs by iteratively using VertexDelete[]

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given the matrix `wam`:

```
wam={
 {∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞,   ∞,  0.180744, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞,  ∞, 0.196146, ∞, ∞, 0.192559}, 
 {∞, ∞, 0.199743, 0.189167, ∞, 0.177828, 0.136293, 0.198179, 
   0.170862, ∞, ∞, 0.150103, 0.152068, ∞, 0.145293, 0.147801}, 
 {∞, 0.17492, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞,  ∞, 0.196928, ∞, 0.18818, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞,  ∞, ∞}, 
 {∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞}, 
 {∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞}, 
 {∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞}, 
 {0.164114, 0.189904, ∞, ∞, ∞, 0.142879, ∞, 0.173485, ∞, 0.195519, ∞,
     0.179716, 0.152131, ∞, ∞, 0.197488}, 
 {0.193476, 0.186542, ∞, 0.196847, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, 
     0.184613, ∞, 0.195341, 0.190637}, 
 {∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞}, 
 {0.17967, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, 0.165566, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, 0.16862, ∞, ∞, ∞}, 
 {∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞},
 {∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞}, 
 {∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, 0.183951, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞}, 
 {∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, 0.189936, 0.16593, 0.197014, ∞, ∞, ∞, 0.194794, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞}, 
 {0.189579, 0.167198, ∞, ∞, ∞,  0.18947, ∞, ∞, ∞, 0.187049, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞, ∞}, 
 {∞, 0.149854, ∞, ∞, ∞, 0.188494, 0.150641, 0.192737, 0.194964, ∞, ∞, ∞, 
   0.14314, 0.15716, 0.14968, ∞}
};
```

I generate the directed graph and its community structure:

```
 vnames = {"AGF", "OIL", "MA1", "MA2", "EGW", "CST", "WHS", "TRS", 
      "HOT", "INF", "FIN", "EST", "ADM", "EDU", "HLT", "ENT"};
 wag = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[vnames, wam, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
     ImageSize -> 250]
 CommunityGraphPlot[wag, FindGraphCommunities[wag]]
```

Then I delete a vertex from the graph `wag` and find the communities in the resulting graph:

```
vdwag = VertexDelete[wag, {"WHS"}]
FindGraphCommunities[vdwag]
 (* {{"OIL", "MA1", "MA2", "TRS", "HOT", "EST", "EDU", "HLT", 
     "ENT"}, {"AGF", "CST", "INF", "ADM"}, {"EGW"}, {"FIN"}} *)
```

Then I wanted to draw the communities using:

```
 CommunityGraphPlot[vdwag, FindGraphCommunities[vdwag]]
```

However, this does not work, although `vdwag` is a graph. WHY?

Comment: It works here. What version of Mathematica do you have? Until very recently, VertexDelete / EdgeDelete have been so buggy as to be completely unusable. Yes, fundamental functions like these were unusably buggy. If you have anything before v12.0, I'd say forget about any reliability when working with `Graph`. Ideally, use 12.2.

Comment: In version 11.3.0, `EdgeWeight`s are not properly modified by`VertexDelete`. A workaround: use `EdgeDelete`, that is, try  `edwag = EdgeDelete[wag, 
  DirectedEdge["WHS", _] | DirectedEdge[_, "WHS"]]`

Comment: @Szabolcs: I have Mathematica version 11.3. Very discouraging bug.

Comment: @kglr: Does this mean that I have to write a long statement to achieve my goal because I have around 16 vertices to delete? I am afraid yes. Thanks.

Comment: My package, IGraph/M, has `IGWeightedVertexDelete` which can handle weighted graphs properly in v11.3 as well. But it will discard all edge properties _except_ weights. There is also `IGTakeSubgraph`, which handles all properties correctly in versions prior to 12.0 as well, but it is very slow.

Comment: Also consider `IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph` and `IGWeightedAdjacencyMatrix` which are actually consistent with each other in the handling of zeros and infinities, unlike the builtin `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` and `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`.

Comment: Finally, IGraph/M has a bunch of properly documented community detection methods. If you ever want to publish this work in a paper, the referee will ask you: what method did you use to find communities? And all you can say "I used Mathematica, I don't know how it works." If you ask Wolfram, [they will not give a satisfactory answer about `FindGraphCommunities`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67390/findgraphcommunities-method-options#comment456444_67390)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you for the detailed comment and suggestions. I tried `IGWeightedVertexDelete[wag, {"WHS"}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]` and it works as I expect it. The resulting directed graph seems to be identical to one @kglr presented. For now, I solved the problem with by @kglr's answer and also by `IGraph`. Thanks to you. and @kglr.

Comment: @kglr: In editing the matrix `wam` how did you insert `Infinity` sign? If I had known how to do it, I would have used the mathematical sign when posting the question. Maybe you have a special program for it.

Comment: Tugrul, I use the browser extension [mathematica editor buttons for stack exchange](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In versions prior to 12.+, due to a bug in `VertexDelete`, (among other things)  `EdgeWeight`s are not properly updated:

```
PropertyValue[vdwag, EdgeWeight] == PropertyValue[wag, EdgeWeight]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

***A work-around:*** use `EdgeDelete` + `VertexDelete`:

```
edwag =  VertexDelete[EdgeDelete[wag, IncidenceList[wag, "WHS"]], "WHS"];

{VertexList[vdwag], EdgeList[vdwag]} == 
  {VertexList[edwag], EdgeList[edwag]}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
CommunityGraphPlot[edwag, FindGraphCommunities[edwag]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

`EdgeDelete` has a similar issue.

If none of the vertices is a `List` we can use the following two functions instead of `VertexDelete` and `EdgeDelete`:

```
ClearAll[vertexDelete, edgeDelete]

vertexDelete = VertexDelete[EdgeDelete[#, IncidenceList[#, #2]], #2] &;

edgeDelete = vertexDelete[#, VertexList@Flatten[{#2}]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
CommunityGraphPlot@vertexDelete[wag, "WHS"]
```

[image]

```
CommunityGraphPlot@vertexDelete[wag, {"WHS", "OIL"}]
```

[image]

```
CommunityGraphPlot@edgeDelete[wag, "AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "WHS"]
```

[image]

```
CommunityGraphPlot@edgeDelete[wag, 
 {"AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "WHS", "MA1" \[DirectedEdge] "OIL"}]
```

[image]